# How to set a string value to an integer cell in datagridview C#

Tags: c#, exception, datagridview

So i have this datagridview:

[image: DataGridView]

In the columns nbjAP if it was less than 0 i want to change it to a string value "Expired"

> error : system.exception expired is not a valid value for int32

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Is there any code that you can provide to show what you have tried so far? It is hard to suggest solutions without knowing what code are working with.

Comment: It appears obvious that the `NbJAP` column is an `int` type column and the error is saying… “Expired” is NOT a valid `int32` value. Change the column to a `string` type.

Comment: How to change the column type without changing it in database

Comment: There are numerous ways to do this, if the data is for “display” only then… I suggest adding a new `Expression` column to the original table, then hide the original NbJAP column. … `dataTable.Columns.Add("NewNbJAP", typeof(string), "IIF(NbJAP < 0,'Expired', NbJAP)");`